# "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? " C# ASP.NET error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am an amateur programmer in C# , ASP.NET . I have decided to create a blog and I have stumbled this problem when I am creating my page for blog post .

Error :

> 'adminpanel_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'submit_btn' and
>   no extension method 'submit_btn' accepting a first argument of type
>   'adminpanel_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

[image: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.]

However, I couldn't solve the problem even if I have hooked up the button with code behind.

[image: This is the properties for the button]

Some extra information :

Front end button code :

```
    <asp:Button ID="post_submit_btn" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="submit_btn" OnDataBinding="submit_btn"  />
```

My references

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;
```

The submit_btn method at code behind :

```
private void submit_btn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = post_submit_btn; 
          button = sender as Button; 

            string blogtitle;
            string blogdes;
            string docPath = @"~/Data/blog_post.xml";
            XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();
            xml_doc.Load(Server.MapPath(docPath));
            XmlNode root;
            root = xml_doc.DocumentElement;

            blogtitle = blog_title.Text.ToString();
            blogdes = blog_des.Value.ToString();

            XmlNode postNode = xml_doc.CreateElement("post-name");
            XmlNode desNode = xml_doc.CreateElement("description");
            XmlNode timeNode = xml_doc.CreateElement("date");
            XmlNode autherNode = xml_doc.CreateElement("Auther");

            postNode.InnerText = blogtitle;
            desNode.InnerText = blogdes;

            postNode.AppendChild(desNode);
            xml_doc.Save(Server.MapPath(docPath));


        }
```

Comment: Did you recompile after binding the Click?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: @VDWWD Yes sir , i have recompiled it

Comment: Side note:  "I am an amateur programmer" - then do yourself a favour and look at MVC. WebForms (aspx) is quickly becoming history and it is _not_ easier to learn.

Comment: set `protected` modifier to your method like `protected void submit_btn(object sender, EventArgs e)`. And, as PaulF said, remove `OnDataBinding` event handler

Comment: @bommelding Alright sir , will look into that sooner , thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Nino Thank you sir , that works . Wonder why is that working sir ?

Comment: @PaulF Hi sir , thank you for the advice , the question is solved , thank you so much sir

Comment: Maybe try cleaning the project/solution and then build

Comment: @mahlatse Thank you for the advice sir, the problem is solved :)